# Windows 7 how to move files from child folders

Tags: windows, windows-7, command, directory

I have folder X, in which i have multiple folders(Y1..Yn) and in each Y folder I have either another folder, or a file which is not a folder.
I am looking for a way to move all the files directly to the folder X and remove all other folders(without having to do this manualy.

Thanks

Comment: In what way is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the Easy Way

1. Go to Folder X
2. In The Search Field, type *.*
3. All the files in the Subfolders will come up
4. Simply Cut/Paste All The Files into Folder X

And Then Select The Empty Folders And Hit Delete

Answer (score 0):

If you run this in `folder X` then it should work to move all files into `folder X` - if there are no filename collisions.

The second line removes empty folders - it's not efficient but it does the job to 10 levels of folders below folder X - and cannot remove any folder with files still inside so is pretty safe.

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (*) do move "%%a" .
for /L %%z in (1,1,10) do for /d /r %%a in (*) do rd "%%a" 2>nul
```